# Saving texture including particle system

Tags: materials, shaders, particles, saving

I made a glass material with bubbles in the thickness. I created it by making a clear glass material to which I added a hair particle system for the bubbles.
I would like to save this material, including the particle system, so I can add it to my material library in order to reuse it in future projects. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to store that object or any other object with that material and the particle system as an asset. But the material and particle system are independent from each other without the mutual object, you cannot store a particle system within a material or vice versa.